# error in corr2 function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to read letter from input image by template matching using corr2 function. For this purpose, I have created templates of number and symbols. 
While running the code for reading letter, i got the following error:

```
Error using corr2
Expected input number 1, A, to be two-dimensional.
```

[image]

MAtlab code for template creation

```
%CREATE TEMPLATES
one=imread('1.png'); 
one=imresize(one,[42 24]);
two=imread('2.png');
two=imresize(two,[42 24]);
three=imread('3.png');
three=imresize(three,[42 24]);
four=imread('4.png');
four=imresize(four,[42 24]);
five=imread('5.png'); 
five=imresize(five,[42 24]);
zero=imread('0.png');
zero=imresize(zero,[42 24]);
sign=imread('sign.png');
sign=imresize(sign,[42 24]);
number=[one two three four  five zero ];
character=[number sign];
NewTemplates1=mat2cell(character,42,[24 24 24 24 24 24 24], 3);
save ('NewTemplates1','NewTemplates1')
clear all
```

matlab code for reading the letter

```
load NewTemplates1 % Loads the templates of characters in the memory.
snap=imread('untitled.png');
snap=imresize(snap,[42 24]); % Resize the input image so it can be compared with the template's images.
comp=[ ];
for n=1:length(NewTemplates1)
    sem=corr2(NewTemplates1{1,n},snap); % Correlation the input image with every image in the template for best matching.
    comp=[comp sem]; % Record the value of correlation for each template's character.
end
vd=find(comp==max(comp)); % Find the index which correspond to the highest matched character.
%*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
% Accodrding to the index assign to 'letter'.
% Alphabets listings.
if vd==1 
    letter='1';
elseif vd==2 
    letter='2';
elseif vd==3
    letter='3';
elseif vd==4 
    letter='4';
elseif vd==5
    letter='5';
elseif vd==6
    letter='0';
elseif vd==7
    letter='sign';
end
```

For kind information: The size of individual component in template is 42x24x3 uint8 and the input image also same dimension. Please provide the suggestion to do further.

Comment: if you add data sample used in the question will be great.

Comment: @nagdwi i have given the input image in the question. I have cropped the letter and sign from the input image and created template in order to do matching task.

Comment: if you add your read images like the following example will be easier to check your code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243972/object-diameter-sphericity-and-ellipse-variance-matlab

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `rgb2gray` to convert rgb to gray images( 2-d matrices) like :

```
%CREATE TEMPLATES
one=rgb2gray(imread('1.png')); 
one=imresize(one,[42 24]);
two=rgb2gray(imread('2.png'));
two=imresize(two,[42 24]);
three=rgb2gray(imread('3.png'));
three=imresize(three,[42 24]);
number=[one two three];
NewTemplates1=mat2cell(number,42,[24 24 24]);
snap=rgb2gray(imread('2Ttt0.png'));
snap=imresize(snap,[42 24]); % Resize the input image so it can be compared with the template's images.
comp=[ ];
for n=1:length(NewTemplates1)
    sem=corr2(NewTemplates1{1,n},snap); % Correlation the input image with every image in the template for best matching.
    comp=[comp sem]; % Record the value of correlation for each template's character.
end
vd=find(comp==max(comp)); % Find the index which correspond to the highest matched character.
%*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
% Accodrding to the index assign to 'letter'.
% Alphabets listings.
if vd==1 
    letter='1';
elseif vd==2 
    letter='2';
elseif vd==3
    letter='3';
elseif vd==4 

end
```

Comment: Thanks Hossein Ka. The code works fine after doing rgb2gray conversion.